# How can I add an extra field in the response to understand which item triggered the search result

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have two simple recipe and ingredient models.

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='name', max_length=200, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='name', max_length=200, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, related_name='recipe_ingredients')
```

I have added a filter for recipe search where I can add ingredient ids as parameter. It returns the recipes which have those ingredients. The filter is as follows,

```
class RecipeFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ingredient_have = django_filters.CharFilter(method='filter_ingredient_have')

    def filter_ingredient_have(self, queryset, name, value):
        if value:
            ids = value.split(',')
            return queryset.filter(Q(ingredients__id__in=ids))
        return queryset


    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = []
```

The url is something like this

```
/recipes/?ingredient_have=id1,id2
```

The response is something like

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "13261f0d-408d-4a51-9cc2-cb69ee72fe24",
            "name": "Curry",
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "id": "08089ff8-03fb-4946-be61-659d799ca996",
                    "name": "oil"
                },
                {
                    "id": "dc9cb6f2-1810-48eb-b7a7-52a4bd9fdccb",
                    "name": "water"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently, the url is giving me the list of recipes if any of the ingredients' id (of any recipe) is id1 or id2. Now I would like to mark that particular ingredient (id1/id2) so that the frontend understands for which ingredient the recipe is in the response. I would like to add an extra field (in Ingredient) so that I can understand in the frontend which ingredient has triggered the recipe to be in the search result such as,

```
{
    "id": "08089ff8-03fb-4946-be61-659d799ca996",
    "name": "oil",
    "highlight": false/true
}
```

The "highlight" field is imaginary here and that's what I would like to achieve.

I hope I made the problem clear. Could you please give me some suggestion/solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your serializers and how does the highlight relate to the ingredients?

Comment: @Sumithran the "highlight" field is imaginary in the last json and thats what I would like to achieve.

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to achive..

Comment: Currently, the url in Question is giving me the recipes if any of the ingredients' id is id1 or id2. Now I would like to mark that particular ingredient (id1/id2) so that the frontend understands for which ingredient the recipe is in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem in serializer,

```
class IngredientSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    isHighlight = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    def get_isHighlight(self, obj):
        ids = []
        if 'request' in self.context and 'ingredient_have' in self.context['request'].query_params:
            ingredient_have = self.context['request'].query_params['ingredient_have']
            if ingredient_have:
                ids.extend(ingredient_have.split(','))
        if str(obj.id) in ids:
            return True
        return False
```

Thats how I can get the query parameters and highlight the ingredient to indicate why this recipe is in the search result.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another field in your "Ingredients" model by simply modifying your `Ingredients()` class. In your case, you'll need a `BooleanField`.

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='name', max_length=200, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    highlight = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Do not forget to use the migrate commands, in order to apply these changes to the database.

Also, adding a field such as `default=False` would prevent any problems for objects already added in your database. You won't need to add the `ingredients` value for each one by hand, because they are going to be automatically assigned a `False` value of it.

Comment: ok... now when the value would be true?

Comment: Well, ingredients added to a certain `Recipe` would build a list of ingredients. So, what you can do is just loop through the entire list and check if the ingredient matches the id you searched for. If yes, try highlighting it.

Comment: Actually that is my question and I would like to do it in backend instead of frontend.

Comment: @sadat You could loop through all your parameters, and try using a thing such as ``Ingredients.objects.filter(id=id1).update(highlight = True)``, but it would be very hard to set it to false after that, because you're making changes in your database. I think frontend would be the most efficient way of doing what you wanted to.

Comment: Please read the question again. I am sorry for poor articulation